# How to make a multicolumn chart using ggplot given one column with binary data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this table produced from a dataframe with 3 million observations.

```
    df_mc_day <- df_clean_distances %>% 
    mutate(weekday = factor(weekdays(df_clean_distances$started_at),levels=c("Monday", 
    "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")), 
    mc=c(member_casual)) %>% tabyl(weekday, member_casual)
    df_mc_day %>% adorn_totals("row")
```

```
     weekday    casual  member
     Monday     147989  261391
     Tuesday    142020  278049
     Wednesday  154818  298865
     Thursday   162762  294189
     Friday     204401  299752
     Saturday   329738  316257
     Sunday     258167  259599
     Total     1399895 2008102
```

I want to make it into a chart that looks like this
[image: desired output chart]

but I can only get ggplot to plot member or casual in two separate graphs. I know it has something to do with mutate but I don't understand what mutate is doing.

```
ggplot() + geom_col( data=df_mc_day, aes(x=weekday, y=member)) 
ggplot() + geom_col( data=df_mc_day, aes(x=weekday, y=casual))
```

[image: Member only graph]
[image: Casual only graph]

Comment: With `ggplot` you need the data in long format i.e. `df_mc_day %>% pivot_longer(cols = -weekday) %>% ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = value, fill = name)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape the data into 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and use that in `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df_mc_day %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -weekday) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = value, fill = name)) + 
       geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
       theme_bw()
```

#### data

```
df_mc_day <- structure(list(weekday = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Total"), casual = c(147989L, 
142020L, 154818L, 162762L, 204401L, 329738L, 258167L, 1399895L
), member = c(261391L, 278049L, 298865L, 294189L, 299752L, 316257L, 
259599L, 2008102L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Wow, I have a ways to go but that worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I can always learn a lot by looking at your answer only :) upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option with `barplot`

```
barplot(
  with(
    df_mc_day,
    t(`rownames<-`(cbind(casual, member), weekday))
  ),
  las = 2,
  beside = TRUE
)
```

which gives
[image]